# Node.js & Express: Need to redirect to specific pages based on POST values (using MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a blog with Node, Express and MongoDB. I'm using Mongoose to connect to MongoDB.

I have a create new post form that creates and saves new posts in MongoDB just fine.

When creating a post you can mark the post as published or leave that option unchecked. When you save the post I want you to either:

A) Be redirected to the home page if the post was published, or
B) be redirected to the post's edit/update page if the post was not marked to be published.

Here's the code in the view that I'm trying to use to accomplish the above:

```
addPost: function(req, res) {
  return new Post(req.body.post).save(function() {
    if (req.body.published === true) {
      return res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      return res.redirect("/office/post/" + [NEED OBJECT ID HERE] + "/edit");
    }
  });
}
```

This is the corresponding view that sends the POST data:

```
form.web-form(method="post", action="/post/new")
  fieldset.fieldset
    label.form-label(for="title") Title
    input.text-input(id="title", type="text", name="post[title]", placeholder="Post title")

    input.text-input(id="alias", type="hidden", name="post[alias]")

    label.form-label(for="subhead") Subhead
    input.text-input(id="subhead", type="text", name="post[subhead]", placeholder="Post subhead")

    label.form-label(for="preview") Preview
    textarea.text-area(id="preview", name="post[preview]", rows="4", placeholder="Preview")

    label.form-label(for="post-body") Body
    textarea.text-area(id="post-body", name="post[body]", rows="5", placeholder="Main content")

    input.check-box(onclick="changeButton()", id="published", type="checkbox", name="post[published]")
    label.inline-label(for="published") Publish

    input.btn-submit(id="submit-post", type="submit", value="Save!")

    a.btn-cancel(href="/") Cancel
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
addPost: function(req, res) {
  // strip 'post[' and ']' from submitted parameters
  var params = {};
  for (var k in req.body)
  {
    params[k.substring(5, k.length - 1)] = req.body[k];
  };
  var post = new Post(params);
  return post.save(function() {
    if (params.published === true) {
      return res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      return res.redirect("/office/post/" + post._id + "/edit");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. I think the POST variable is fine as is. When I log `request.body.post` to the console it spits out:
    { title: 'test',
      alias: '',
      subhead: '',
      preview: '',
      body: '',
      published: 'on' }
I think I have to figure out how to get the Object ID from the just saved Post object in order to pass to the URL (which would then match the edit post view). Also, I just changed the first part to: `if (req.body.post.published) {
          return res.redirect("/");
        }` and that fixed that part.

Comment: 'Plain' Express doesn't handle that type of property naming I believe, hence the extra code to handle them (but if it works for you without it, great :). Did you notice `post._id` in the redirect? Mongoose should populate it when saving.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Here's how the code ended up looking: `addPost: function(req, res) {
      var newPost;
      newPost = new Post(req.body.post);
      return newPost.save(function() {
        if (req.body.post.published) {
          return res.redirect("/");
        } else {
          return res.redirect("/office/post/" + newPost._id + "/edit");
        }
      });
    }` Appreciate the help!